Compare two PySpark DataFrames and append the results side by side
I have two pySpark DataFrames, need to compare those two DataFrames column wise and append the result next to it.
DF1:



Claim_number
Claim_Status




1001
Closed


1002
In Progress


1003
open



Df2:



Claim_number
Claim_Status




1001
Closed


1002
open


1004
In Progress



Expected Result in pySpark:
DF3:



Claim_number_DF1
Claim_number_DF2
Comparison_of_Claim_number
Claim_status_DF1
Claim_status_DF2
Comparison_of_Claim_Status




1001
1001
TRUE
Closed
Closed
TRUE


1002
1002
TRUE
In Progress
Open
FALSE


1003
1004
FALSE
open
In Progress
FALSE




What is your actual question? What have you tried?

I want to compare two dataframe and if the column value matches it should populate True and if it not matches it should populate False next to the column

That's not a question, that's asking SO to write your code for you.

Sorry i dont understand your question...

Unlike Pandas dataframes PySpark dataframes are not ordered. So the task is not doable unless a criterium is provided which rows of each dataframe should be compared. Simply saying "take the third row from df1 and compare it with the third row from df2" does not work unfortunately. There is no "third row", at least not when using large datasets with multiple partitions.

DF(s) are nor ordered but distributed in different places so this is an invalid ask.
However what you can do instead is following -

You can assume DF1 is master DF and join it with DF2 using Claim_number and if DF2 has no claim number then depending on join type, you can choose to ignore (inner join) or produce then as null(left outer join)

If that is what yous ask is, then here is the solution.
final_Df = df1.join(df2, Claim_number, "inner").distinct()

